# rsyslog or a similar distributed logging standard, for Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have a bunch of Windows Servers that run a bunch of apps, that log into local text files.

I want to aggregate these text files into a centralized log server, where I can search them. Building something like that is trivial, but before reinventing the wheel I wonder if there is already something?

Would rsyslog help? Is there even a Windows Version of it?

It needs to run on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

Splunk? http://www.splunk.com
You get the centralized logging and searching all together, and there is a windows version

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [Kiwi Syslog](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/) they have been bought by SolarWinds who hid the [free version here](http://www.solarwinds.com/register/registration.aspx?program=874&c=70150000000EIVC)

Comment: I want to secure the communication between client and server. Hence, I was looking at a rsyslog server vs syslog server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use rsyslog under cygwin if that's acceptable.

Now you just need to make sure that your applications use the syslog protocol to do their logging.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk index the log files and help you fastly search. To push all the Windows log files to syslog server you need an agent. [Datagram SyslogAgent](http://syslogserver.com/download.html) likely is the best option. Also give [Snare Agent](http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/SnareWindows/index.html) or [NTSyslog](http://ntsyslog.sourceforge.net/) a try if you want.